# Navigation items not rendering in correct position in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, navigation, background-image

I am using leaves as background images for items in my navigation bar on [this site](http://nickputman.com/).  All looks fine in Chrome and Safari, but in Firefox the three leaves are rendering at different positions on the x axis, as in the following image:

[image]

The only leaf that is rendering in the correct position is the 'about me' leaf.  The 'home' leaf is rendering about 20px lower than it should and the 'contact' leaf about 5px lower.  I wonder if someone can spot why this is happening?

The html for the leaves and the css is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <a href="/index.html" id="home"><img class='hoverImg_normal' src='images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png'/><img class='hoverImg_highlight' src='images/bodhi-leaf-green.png'/><img class='text home' src='images/home.png'/></a>
    <a href="about.html" id="about"><img class='hoverImg_normal' src='images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png'/><img class='hoverImg_highlight' src='images/bodhi-leaf-green.png'/><img class='text about' src='images/about.png'/></a>
    <a href="contact.html" id="contact"><img class='hoverImg_normal' src='images/bodhi-leaf-brown.png'/><img class='hoverImg_highlight' src='images/bodhi-leaf-green.png'/><img class='text' src='images/contact.png'/></a>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
nav{
    text-align:center;
    height:170px;
}
nav a{
    width:115px;
    height:170px;
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 50px;
}

nav a>img{
    width:115px;
    height:170px;
}

nav a>img.hoverImg_normal{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    z-index:2;/*Put image behind text*/
}

nav a>img.hoverImg_highlight{
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:-174px;/*5 + 1 for text*/
    opacity:0;
    transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s; /* Firefox 4 */
    -webkit-transition: 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
    -o-transition: 1s; /* Opera */
    z-index:2;
}

nav a:hover>img.hoverImg_highlight{
    opacity:1;
}

nav a>img.text {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    top:-267px;
}

.about {
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.home {
    margin-top: 8px;
}
```

Comment: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: it seems like you might be getting a little too hard core with your selector style.  check out number 8 on this link: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/<br>...  also - it would make sense to have your nav links in a list.  and if you can - use fonts for your text instead of images.  i commend you for your desire to embrace all the details of css, much what you are doing is much more simple that this.  I suggest you dial it back and start over.  (i also like to make a .trans and keep the transition stuff in that class.

Comment: have you tried just making the leaf images background images?

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems:

1. Your text-images are of different height, you should try and use three images of the same height
2. Using the same image height still results in different positions due to the different margin-top for the .about and the .home class. Additionally there is no definition for the .contact class, and the contact text-image has no "contact" class in it's attribute in contrast to the texts of home and about.

One more thing: You should use an alternative text for images, such as:

```
<img class='text home' src='images/home.png' alt='home' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute positioning instead of pulling the images up with a negative `top` value. Very easy to do since you already include **jQuery**. The snippet below calculates the appropriate `top` value depending on the `top` value of `#main` and the images' `height`:

```
var lft = [397, 617, 836];//I calculated those using jQuery
var cur = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hoverImg_highlight").each(function() {
        var tp = parseInt($("#main").offset().top, 10) - praseInt($(this).height(), 10);
        $(this).css({position: 'absolute', top: tp, left: lft[cur]});
        cur ++;
    });
});
```

I might have a typo here or there, but I hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

check out this jsfiddle.  this is a bare bones version of what you are doing.  (i think)  http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6HcdC/